I am a word of letters three
I am a word of letters three,
Remove just one letter and I still sound the same.
You can find me in a month, a day, or even in a name.
What am I?

Is the answer:

 ARE?

I am a word of letters 3:

ARE has 3 letters.

Remove just one letter and I sound the same:

ARE without the e gives AR, which sounds the same as ARE.

You can find me in a month, a day, or even in a name:

 ARE sounds like r, which can be found in a month (March), a day (Thursday), and a name (Mark).

What am I?:

 ARE

